# Yet another evaluating limit question: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2-4}\right)^{3n^2+5}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

How do I begin to evaluate this limit: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2-4}\right)^{3n^2+5}$$

Does it equal to $e^{-1}$? (Please don't use ln.)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $m=n^2-4$, and

$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{3m+17}=\left[\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{m}\right]^3=\frac1{e^3}$$

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to prove this without changing n to m?

Comment: The basic idea behind this proof is to transform the limit to a representation of the natural base $e$ (As you prohibit the use of $\ln$). So, mi dispiace I cannot think of a way without doing this $m$ thing.

Comment: OK then why is it ok to remove the 17 from the exponent? also, why doesn't it matter if m tends to infinity isntead of n?

Comment: Formally, $\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{3m+17}=\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{3m}\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{17}$. But $\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{17}$ approaches $1$ as $m\to\infty$, so does not affect the limit.

Comment: Intuitively $m\rightarrow\infty$ such that 17 is really negligible in comparsion to it. If you are unhappy with this explanation, notice that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac1m)^{17}=1$. As for the latter question, refer to the equation $m=n^2-4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\longrightarrow‎ \infty$
 and $‎u\longrightarrow‎
 1$ , then $\lim _{n‎\rightarrow \infty}u^v‎\longrightarrow‎
\exp (\lim_{n‎\rightarrow \infty} v(u-1))$.

So, we have
 $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2-4}\right)^{3n^2+5}=exp(\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2-4}-1\right)({3n^2+5})=exp(\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(-\frac{3n^2+5}{n^2-4}\right))\\
=exp(-3)$$